# stuck with how this ordinary differential equation changes in new coordinates?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, coordinate-systems, chain-rule

I am studying ordinary differential equations. There are some solved examples in my book to learn the material from. For this one below however, I do not know how this part of the solution is derived.

The book says, $y'''+yy''=0$ , under $r=xy$ and $s=\ln x $, changes to

$$s_r s_{rrr}+r s_r^2 s_{rr}-3s_{rr}^2=0 $$

How this latter equation is derived? I tried chain rule but I had $r_x $ and $s_x$, which clearly can not be correct.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure there’s no typo?

Comment: I checked it again. Arrigo book. symmetry method. page 59. that is what he says.

Answer (score 1):

In the question it is assumed that Eq.$(1)$ :
$$y'''+yy''=0 \tag 1$$

is transformed into Eq.$(2)$ :

$$s_r s_{rrr}+r s_r^2 s_{rr}-3s_{rr}^2=0 \tag 2$$

thanks to the change of variables : $\quad\begin{cases} r=xy \\ s=\ln x \end{cases}$

If this assumption is true any solution $y(x)$ of Eq.$(1)$ is transformed into $s(r)$ which is a solution of Eq.$(2)$.

For example try with $y(x)=x$ which is an obvious solution of $(1)$.

The change of variables transforms $y(x)=x$ into $s(r)=\frac12\ln(r)$.

$s_r=\frac{1}{2r} \quad;\quad s_{rr}=-\frac{1}{2r^2} \quad;\quad s_{rrr}=\frac{1}{r^3}$

$s_r s_{rrr}+r s_r^2 s_{rr}-3s_{rr}^2=\frac{1}{2r}(\frac{1}{r^3})+r(\frac{1}{2r})^2(-\frac{1}{2r^2})-3(-\frac{1}{2r^2})^2$

$s_r s_{rrr}+r s_r^2 s_{rr}-3s_{rr}^2=\frac{1}{r^4}(\frac12-\frac{1}{8}-\frac{3}{4})=-\frac{3}{8r^4}\neq 0$

The transformed function $s(r)$ is not solution of Eq.$(2)$.

This proves that the initial assumption is false. Possibly there is a typo in the question or a misunderstanding in the context.